# Find out if eigenvalues and eigenvectors belong to a matrix, and if yes, find the matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

So in my Linear Algebra course I am given the following eigenvalues with their eigenvectors and I have to find out if they belong to a matrix, and if yes, to find the matrix. So this is given:

$\lambda_1=-4$ and $\vec{v_1} =\begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 0 \\ -6\\5 \end{bmatrix} \;$
$\lambda_2=2$ and $\vec{v_2} =\begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 0 \\ 0\\1 \end{bmatrix} \;$
$\lambda_3=2$ and $\vec{v_3} =\begin{bmatrix} 2\\ 1 \\ 0\\0 \end{bmatrix} \;$
$\lambda_4=1$ and $\vec{v_4} =\begin{bmatrix} -1\\ -1 \\ 0\\0 \end{bmatrix} \;$
So I have to find out if they belong to a matrix, and if yes to find that matrix.
I first write the Matrix $X$ with the column vectors:
$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 2 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1\\
-6& 0 & 0 & 0\\
5 & 1 & 0& 0\\
\end{bmatrix}$

I find that the determinant of this matrix is 6, which means it is invertible, now I find $X^{-1}$
$\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{6} & 0\\
0 & 0 & \frac{5}{6} & 1\\
1 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & -2 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}$

Lasty I Construct the diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues :

D= $\begin{bmatrix} 
-4 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
0& 0& 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$

Now to find $A$ I use this property $A=XDX^{-1}$
When I do this computation, I get the following matrix for A

A= $\begin{bmatrix} 
3 & -2& 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -4 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -\frac{5}{3} & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}$

However, using this matrix, when I do $(A+4I)$ so using $\lambda_1=-4$ I find an eigenvector

$v_1= \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 0\\ 3.6\\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $ which is not the same as $\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\ -6\\5 \end{bmatrix}$ from the original problem.

So now I am a bit lost, did I make a mistake somewhere, or does this mean that the second, third and fourth are eigenvectors and eigenvalues of matrix $A$ but the first one is not?

Comment: The entry (4,3) of matrix $A$ should be $5$, not $-5/3$.

Comment: Thanks, now If I compute $\lambda_1=1$ I get $v_1=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$ instead of $\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ -1\\ 0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: If the geometric multiplicity of an eigenvalue is $1$, the eigenvectors are determined up to a scalar factor. In your case you are obtaining $-v_1$ so this is correct. In general you can completely determine the eigenspaces and the "chosen" eigenvectors will be a basis of that eigenspace, so eigenvectors are not uniquely determined.